# Select most recent record based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a select query that returns the most recent record from the table based on date. Basically whichever row's `[Date]` field is closest to the current date.

Sample Data:

```
    ID       Content         Date
--------------------------------------------
1   1050    Test Values    2013-11-27 10:46:24.900
2   1051    Test Test      2013-11-27 10:47:43.150
3   1057    Test Testx2    2013-11-27 10:48:22.820
```

I would like to only return these values

```
    ID       Content         Date
--------------------------------------------
1   1057    Test Testx2    2013-11-27 10:48:22.820
```

Thanks!

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Try: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <TableName> ORDER BY Date DESC

Comment: `Date` is not a valid name for a column; it is a type name. (SQL is _not_ case sensitive)

Comment: @wildplasser I just used `[Date]` as an example. My actual column name is `[Timestamp]`.

Comment: You can use it as a column name in SQL Server 2008 if you wrap it in quare brackets.

Comment: I love it - the only answer that was correct from the beginning doesn't even get an upvote :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Table
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: No, this gives the oldest entry and won't work as you're not specifying the fields you want to select or `*`.

Comment: @Thorten Thanks! It took me few seconds to check it in management studio, because I didn't remember the syntax of TOP

Comment: Yep, this worked. I simply changed `*` to the fields that I needed.

Comment: use brackets for date, is a reserved word in SQL Server 2008+

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you want your query to work on any DBMS (not just SQL Server), use [ANSI SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011):

```
select * from t order by Date desc limit 1
```

or

```
select * from t where Date = (select max(Date) from t)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

This returns all fields from the first record after sorting from the highest date to the lowest. Essentially this returns the newest entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1  ID,Content,Date FROM <TABLE_NAME> ORDER BY Date
```